# How floats are computed on a machine without an FPU

Tags: c, floating-point

C language has a data-type `float`. Some machines have a floating point processor that carries out all the floating point computations. My question is: Could there be some machines without a floating point processor? How do such machines use floating point?

Comment: yes. Like back in the 8086 days....

Comment: @MitchWheat: much later than that :)

Comment: @leppie: when you get to this age, it's all 8086's  !!  ;)

Comment: there are some DSP processors without FPU's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many small controllers do not have floating point units.  In that case, there is a floating point software library.

In the mid-1980s, we considered ourselves blessed if our system had an 8087, the FPU for the 8086 and 8088.  Unfortunately our software had to work correctly if an 8087 was present or not.  That meant trapping and emulating 8087 instructions if it was missing.

Answer (score 5):

The c standard allows floating points.

It is the compiler's responsibility to translate it to the specific hardware architecture.

If the hardware [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) supports floating points [and most modern machines do], then - the compiler will most likely use it.

Otherwise, it will have to create a native language code that simulates the behavior of floating points by its own. How is it done? You could read more about floating points in the [wikipeida page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and in this more detailed article about [floating point arithmetics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3):

Up till and including the 486SX, no CPU's had a a builtin FPU unit.

As for microcontrollers, most of them do not have a FPU unit.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "built-in", but please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z4_(computer), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray-1, among other examples of computers with floating-point that predate the Intel 486DX.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find that nearly all modern desktop computers and servers include a FPU.

High end mobile devices have begun to include FPUs, but not all of them have them. And if we're talking about mobile devices other than at the high end, you won't find many devices that have FPUs.

In many applications, it's possible to do arithmetic on fractional numbers using "fixed point arithmetic"--that doesn't require an FPU.

In other cases, you can do the same math that an FPU does, but it takes longer when you have to build it yourself out of other arithmetic primitives rather than having a complex chip take care of it for you.

My favorite example of floating point simulation on fixed point processors is provided in [Donald Knuth's MMIXware](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/mmix-20110831.tar.gz), a complete processor simulation in very portable C.

Answer (score 1):

Emulating floating point is a bit slow, but theoretically fairly simple. It's just about like most people learned in high school or so: you have a number with an exponent. To add or subtract, you have to adjust the numbers so they have the same exponents, then add/subtract the mantissas. To multiply or divide, you multiply/divide the mantissas and add/subtract the exponents.

When you've finished that, you normalize the result. In high school we used decimal, and normally required exactly one digit before the decimal point, so (for example) 10001 would be written as 1.0001 x 10<sup>4</sup>. On the computer, the details are a bit different (e.g., we're dealing in binary instead of decimal) but the basic idea is pretty much the same.